# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' - SQL Database Error

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting this error when trying to instantiate a new `Cart`, I do not understand why it thinks `clientId` is an `int`.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        string clientId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (clientId != null)
        {

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            int amount = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAmount.SelectedValue);

            Cart cart = new Cart
            {
                Amount = amount,
                ClientID = clientId,
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                IsInCart = true,
                ProductID = id
            };

            CartModel model = new CartModel();
            lblResult.Text = model.InsertCart(cart);
        }
        else
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Please log in to order items";
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is with;

```
 Cart cart = new Cart
            {
                Amount = amount,
                **ClientID = clientId,**
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                IsInCart = true,
                ProductID = id
            };
```

But from what I can see, it is set as a `String` - and the datatype in my database is a `Varchar`.

Interestingly, if I comment the `ClientID = clientiD` line out, my website allows me to use the program and when I click my Submit button, it adds everything to the database but sets the `ClientID` to `0`. But this is no use to me further down the line.

Thanks!

Comment: Right Click over `Cart` and select "Go to definition" so you can see how `ClientID` is declare on that class

Comment: what does the class definition of `Cart` look like?

Comment: `string clientId` is the string which cant convert to int as the error says

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Thank you - I did not think to look there. This is just a project I am doing for a learning curve and a bit of fun, so thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> it adds everything to the database but sets the ClientID to 0

Looks like ClientID in your table is numeric type. In that case you should convert your string variable to a numeric variable and use that.

You can use `Int32.TryParse` to safely convert the string value to an int value.

```
string clientIdStr = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIdStr))
{
  //your existing code to get other values
  if (Int32.TryParse(clientIdStr , out int clientId))
   {
        //use clientId int value now 
        var cart = new Cart
        {
            Amount = amount,
            ClientID = clientId,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            IsInCart = true,
            ProductID = id
        };          
   }
}
```

Also make sure your Cart class's ClientId is numeric type now

```
public class Cart
{
   public int ClientId { set;get;}
   //other properties goes here
}
```

Comment: It seems as though the OP thinks this should be a string, and it's a string according to the Db.  a more appropriate answer would be to change the `Cart` model, if that indeed is the problem

Comment: **it adds everything to the database but sets the ClientID to 0** This clearly explains what his db structure is. If ClientId is his Cart table is string, he won;t get an error when trying to set a string value to that.